# how to fix Cannot read property 'name' of undefined react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i want to pull out name from redux store by using useSelector hook, and want to edit that value and save back to store and update ui. to edit name initially i'm using useState hook but it gives the error of property name

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import TodoReducer from "./TodoSlice";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    todo: TodoReducer
  }
});
```

**todoSlice.js** for initial state and reducers logic actions

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = [
  { id: "1", name: "First Post!", description: "Hello!" },
  { id: "2", name: "Second Post", description: "More text" }
];

const TodoSlice = createSlice({
  name: "todos",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    todoAdded(state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    todoUpdated(state, action) {
      const { id, name, description } = action.payload;
      const existingTodo = state.entities[id];
      if (existingTodo) {
        existingTodo.name = name;
        existingTodo.description = description;
      }
    }
  }
});

export const { todoAdded, todoUpdated } = TodoSlice.actions;
export default TodoSlice.reducer;
```

and **EditTodo.js** here importing action **todoUpdated** from **TodoSlice**, and using store as useSelector hook, it looks everything is up here but it gives error, i don't know how to solve this error if someone knows please solve this... [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-hooks-hmcpl?file=/src/Components/EditTodo.js) link for full app code

Answer (score 0):

the useState hook doesn't update your reducer. Also you are not actually setting the todo the right way. You get the todo by this:

```js
 const todo = useSelector((state) =>
    state.todo.find((todo) => todo.id === todoId)
  );
```

You can just use the todo.name without using a state. The reducer is already updating the todo as well because of the useSelector hook functions as a state.

Edit:

You actually need the state because you only call the dispatcher on save click. I think you can just keep the useState as is, just change it so that the useSelector is actually selecting the todo as I mentioned

Comment: thanks for answer. i have tried as you mentioned above, but now it is giving another error of useHistory from react-router [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-hooks-hmcpl?file=/src/Components/EditTodo.js) to codesandbox editTodo.js